# Create Teams link while creating Outlook Calendar Event through graph api

Tags: elixir, microsoft-graph-calendar, microsoft-graph-teams, outlook-calendar

I am trying to integrate outlook calendar in my elixir application.

I referred https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http link to create the calendar event.

I am not able to create the meeting link for the calendar event.

One can create the teams meeting link when he creates via calendar (GUI) so I am sure there must be a way for this. I guess I am missing a Key to pass to create the meeting link.

My request url - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events

My request Payload is

```
    {
        "start" => start_time,
        "end" => end_time,
        "attendees" =>[
            %{
              "type" => "required",
              "emailAddress" => %{
                "address" => attendee.email,
                "name" => ""
              }
            }]
        "body" => %{
          "contentType" => "HTML",
          "content" => description
        },
        "location" => %{"displayName" => location},
        "subject" => summary
      }
```

The payload is printed here in elixir format but I am converting it to normal JSON object and sending.. I am able to create the event but not able to create the meeting link along with it.

Please help me create the meeting link.. Thanks

Comment: Is "weblink" in the response the link you are looking for?

Comment: Thank @AndreyGordeyev but no I was not looking for weblink.. but after more of my finding I got to know that microsoft graph api does not give support to create online meeting url as of now.. although there is a beta url to do so.. https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/events so I uses the beta url to create the online meeting teams link...